# How to only show all time leaderboard (suppress daily and weekly leaderboards)

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm adding support for the **Google-Play Game-Services** to my Sports-App and was going to use the leaderboard so users can compare their number of workouts to other users.

But the number of workouts isn't a score in the sense, the leaderboard needs it and only makes sense if it's not restricted to a time span.

So I would like to only show the all-time leaderboard. I'm using the **default leaderboard** activity provided by the `GameClient` and that unfortunately has a selection for daily, weekly and all-time leaderboards.

Is there any way to tweak this or am I doomed to implement a leaderboard by myself? Or are there any examples of custom leaderboard implementations available?

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution? I also would like to suppress daily and weekly leaderboards.

Comment: @LA_: no, I think there's no way to achieve that with the default activities. I tweaked my game-play / definition of achievements so its somewhat okay with daily and weekly leaderboards, as I didn't want to implement a leaderboard myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot change that as you only have access to the intent to the activity so you can't modify this. It is enforced by Google to promote adding friends to your G+ circles.